# How to execute a file from python

Tags: python

by open and don't mean as in making a file for me to open later i know how to do that. by open i mean that when i run the code it will open the file and i can see it in front of me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you want to launch the application associated with a particular file.

Use [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) for that.

For example, on my computer, this would open the spreadsheet with Microsoft Excel:

```
import os
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Pinkman\Fat Stacks.xlsx")
```

Comment: yeah i remembered i read something about it but i was having trouble importing os because i was using the wrong interpreter so i forgot it

Answer (score 0):

```
import io
import sys
import builtins
import traceback
from functools import wraps


def opener(old_open):
    @wraps(old_open)
    def tracking_open(*args, **kw):
        file = old_open(*args, **kw)

        old_close = file.close
        @wraps(old_close)
        def close():
            old_close()
            open_files.remove(file)
        file.close = close
        file.stack = traceback.extract_stack()

        open_files.add(file)
        return file
    return tracking_open


def print_open_files():
    print(f'### {len(open_files)} OPEN FILES: [{", ".join(f.name for f in 
open_files)}]', file=sys.stderr)
    for file in open_files:
        print(f'Open file {file.name}:\n{"".join(traceback.format_list(file.stack))}', 
file=sys.stderr)


open_files = set()
io.open = opener(io.open)
builtins.open = opener(builtins.open)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code and what it's trying to achieve?

Comment: So what I have done here is that I have wrapped a built-in file object at the starting point of the program itself. 

Well, it basically told me on the whole that the loggers were not being closed which ended up resulting in the error.